Mudblazor `<MudCheckBox>`, `<MudRadio>` and `<MudSwitch>` not working in static SSR account pages
anyone have workaround or possible solution, to make those three components from MudBlazor to work in default Blazor template Account/... pages who are always Static SSR.
I found that <MudTextField> can be handled with extra Name="some_name" property. I know this from FluentUI. But with those all switches none of my solutions worked. You just can't press them. And after debuggind if i press them and then proceed to submit button, they shows error that value is 'on' not true/false or 0/1.

MudBlazor needs interactivity to work, doesn't work in SSR. Mentioned in their README https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor?tab=readme-ov-file#prerequisites

You could try put the "mud form" in an custom component, then use this component in account pages with interactive.
<CustomComponent @rendermode=InteractiveServer></CustomComponent>

